# Регулярные выражения как правильно соотнести соответсвуюшие значения для ключа указанного ранее перед самим значением

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое выражение где сначала идет имя параметра/ключа, а потом его значение через пробел

```
str = "High_Level 1.18512 lowlevel 1.16504"
```

Как должно быть:

```
High_Level =  1.18512
lowlevel   =  1.16504
```

Comment: Вам нужно заменить исходный текст на приведённый результат? Или получить числа в переменные при помощи какого-то языка программирования?

Comment: получить числа в соответсвуюшие переменные (работаю на питоне)

Comment: достаточно получить числа в переменные , сам исходный текст не трогаем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить подобный способ создания словаря через регулярные выражения, когда ищем текстовую часть для создания ключа словаря и, через пробел, соответствующее ему значение в виде десятичного числа.

```
import re

str_ = "High_Level 1.18512 lowlevel 1.16504"

d = dict(re.findall('(\w+)\s*(\d+\.\d+)', str_))
# {'High_Level': '1.18512', 'lowlevel': '1.16504'}
```

Также советую не называть переменные в виде зарезервированных слов, таких как `str`

Comment: Все Спасибо Вам работает :)

Answer (score 1):

Словарь пойдёт в качестве "переменных"?

```
s = "High_Level 1.18512 lowlevel 1.16504"
v = dict((k, float(v)) for k,v in zip(*[iter(s.split())]*2))
print(v)
```

```
{'High_Level': 1.18512, 'lowlevel': 1.16504}
```

Comment: интересный вариант :) но хотел именно через регулярку Спасибо !!!